# facet_wrap does not split data used for filling geom_point at the facet level

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am building "heat maps" for different variables using the `facet_wrap` function and `geom_point`. The color (fill) of each point should be relative to the value of each variable. Instead, the fill color takes the whole data.frame regardless the variable and I end up with wrong fill color.

My data.frame has a "melt function"-like structure meaning my variables are under a single column (colname = "wellcolor"). `facet_wrap` splits each variable and display heat maps nicely. But the fill color, relative to the value (colname = Well_N) takes the max and min values within the entire dataframe instead of the min and max value within the desired variable.

```
p <- ggplot(MyMap, aes(y=y,x=x, label=Well_N)) + 
  geom_point(shape=22,  aes(fill = as.numeric(MyMap$Well_N)), 
             size =32*(12/COLUMN),
             show.legend = FALSE)  +
  facet_wrap(~wellcolor, ncol = 1,  scales = "free", shrink = FALSE)
```

I would like to kind of split MyMap$well_N so the fill color reflects the value (relative to the min and max values) of the variable displayed in the facet.

Comment: You can make separate plots and arrange them side by side.

Comment: Might have something to do with the fact that you're using MyMap$Well_N instead of just Well_N in the fill argument.

Comment: thank you. I found  a workaround. I made a new column with normalized values... as simple as that!